# How can I use a VPN for specific applications which then connect to multiple squid IP's?

Tags: vpn, proxy, squid, flash, socks

Ok here is my exceptionally confusing dilemma I'm hoping someone here can help me with.

1) I have a home computer setup to check my remote website's functionality & load time.
2) I have 5 remote servers running squid (in different countries) each server has 5 IP's

Right now I simply use Internet explorer on my HOME-PC, I set the IP & port of each Squid IP & have a script to automatically check the website's functionality.

It gives me a load time in "real-world" standards from the different locations.

Here is my problem.  When using the squid proxy IP's, they work for everything, with the exception of Flash. Somehow Flash bypasses my local proxy settings & my home-pc ends up loading the flash movie/data etc. through my own home-connection.

So...Now my question is....

1) is the best way to ensure all data passes through my remote servers setting up a VPN?

& if so....

2) how will I tell Internet Explorer to first connect to the remote VPN & then to the remote Squid?

& if not....

3) Is there a better setup other than VPN/SQUID, perhaps SOCKS/5 to ensure that all data over a given IP set in Internet Explorer ensures all data transferred does not revert to my home connection?

Comment: In your browser set the squid as your HTTP proxy and then reload the site. This will ensure that all and any traffic is sent to your squid server. So unless your squid server is redirecting you to a domain it is not handling it will work.

Is that what you were doing in Step 1?

Answer (score 0):

VPN or SOCKS will just complicate it further. My recommendation is to keep it simple and easy.

We have many users using our Squid proxies to surf the web, and never ever have problems with Flash not using the proxy. It doesn't have its own settings; it just looks at IE and uses that.

Use Firefox with the [Foxyproxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/) plugin to quickly switch between all your different proxies.